# Converting hex character to decimal

Tags: c++, converting

Is it possible to make this code more efficient & elegant?

```
int HexToDecimal(char ch)
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
    if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f')
    {
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    }
    else if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9')
    {
        return ch - '0';
    }
    printf("Error\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**: Printing error could be ignored. By returning 0 I only mean to show that the input char is not a hex digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory (I haven't checked it) this should be the most efficient in terms of speed at the cost of a small increase in memory footprint.

Note that it does not repeat your `printf("Error\n")` smell.

```
return
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // <nul> ... <si>
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // <dle> ... <us>
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // ' ' ... '/'
"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // '0' ... '?'
"\x00\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // '@' 'A' ... 'O'
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // 'P' ... 'Z' ... '_'
"\x00\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // '`' 'a' ... 'o'
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" // 'p' ... 'z' ... '~' <del>
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" /// Accented/Extended
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
[c];
```

**Added**

Apologies for not being clear. This solution is not "better" than the original, just different and provably faster. I would use the originally posted code in all cases except when maximum speed is critical and only then after careful deliberation.

I posted this for completeness, it is not elegant in any way, it is only more efficient ... almost brutally so.

Comment: What about endianness?

Comment: @Cygal: Not applicable because it is char.

Comment: Clever but a -1 `\0xFF` to indicate error would have been useful so that you can check for error.

Comment: I wish I knew what I was looking at.

Comment: @RyanMiller: Its a string with 256 characters. You the use the character `c` (which has a value of 0->255) as the index into the string. It returns a character from the string. The string is carefully constructed so that character 51 in the array returns the character \x03. Thus '3'(ie 51) when used as an index will return '\x03' which converts to the integer 3.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for the assist. I agree with the \0xff point, unfortunately asker used 0.

Answer (score 2):

The first idea comming to mind is to check `0 <= ch <=9` before `tolower(ch)`, because if it's a digit, then you don't need to make `tolower`.

Say, what does it means if the function returns `0`? How to determine the case "it returns `0` because out of hex digits range" and "because ch is `0`"?

Comment: Updated the question. By returning 0 I only mean to show that the input char was not a hex digit.

Comment: @Meysam, what does it return when you pass '0'?

Answer (score 1):

As fogbit said, first check for digits, then `tolower` if necessary.  By the way, unless you wrote your own `tolower`, it should probably be `std::tolower`.

Don't print anything on error.  Either `assert` that the value is correct, return an impossible value (-1 is commonly used), or throw an exception.  Printing that there was an error does not tell the rest of your program what happened.

Finally, do you really need to write this?  Are you sure your numbers won't be in the form `0xABCD`, which can be converted just fine with `boost::lexical_cast` or an `std::stringstream` wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Now for elegance (forgive me ... my C is a little rusty):

```
static char * Hex = "0123456789abcdef";
char * found = strchr(Hex, tolower(ch));
return found != null ? found - Hex: 0;
```

We search for the character in the string. If found then the value is the offset of the found character from the start of the string.